# How can I highlight C syntax in CUDA (.cu) files in nano?

Tags: cuda, nano

I've already highlighted C syntax for `.c` files in `nano` by adding `include "usr/share/nano/c.nanorc"` to `~/.nanorc`.

Unfortunately, this only works for `.c` files, not for `.cu` (CUDA) files.

How can I enable C syntax highlighting for files ending `.cu`?

Answer (score 3):

Change this line (or similar, probably first non-comment line) in `/usr/share/nano/c.nanorc`

```
syntax "c" "\.(c(c|pp|xx)?|C)$" "\.(h(h|pp|xx)?|H)$" "\.ii?$"
```

to:

```
syntax "c" "\.(c(c|pp|u|xx)?|C)$" "\.(h(h|pp|xx)?|H)$" "\.ii?$"
```

If you don't have permission to change `/usr/share/nano/c.nanorc`:

1. copy it to your home, for example to `~/.c.nanorc`
2. change syntax as shown above
3. change include in `~/.nanorc`:

from:

```
include "usr/share/nano/c.nanorc"
```

to:

```
include "~/.c.nanorc"
```